# How to redirect user to the desired page after login using LoginRequiredMixin in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have created a mini project called **ToDoList App**. I have used **class based views** for create, update and delete functions. There is MyTasks icon on navbar.

**What I want?**
If the user is not logged in and he clicks on MyTasks icon, he should be redirected to the login page and after login to MyTasks page.

I have used `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'` and `LOGIN_URL='login'` in `settings.py` file

If I write `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'task_list'`, it is working fine else not.

Below is the code from `views.py` file:

```
class TaskListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    """List of all tasks."""

    model = MyTasks
    context_object_name = 'tasks'
    template_name = 'task_list.html'
```

This is from `urls.py` file:

```
path('tasks/', views.TaskListView.as_view(), name="task_list"),
```

I have used the attribute `redirect_field_name='next'` and tried to override dispatch method in the above class, still it is not working.

The output I am getting is, after login, it is getting redirected to homepage instead of my tasks page. 
 Any help is much appreciated.

Below is the screenshot from the terminal:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtsIG.png

Answer (score 0):

You should use absolute path instead of reverse url.
if you want to use reverse urls you need to use `reverse` function.

for example:

```
from django.urls import reverse


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse("app_name:url_name")
```

but this is a global setting and will work for all of your views.
if you want to do it just for one of your views you can do it:

```
class YourView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/' # defaults to settings.LOGIN_URL
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to' # querystring name => ? redirect_to=current_url
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine when I added this line in login.html in form tag file: `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}">`